# Send Marketing Cloud Email button is asking me to login again

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a button called "Send Marketing Cloud Email" on contact detail page. It is asking me to login again when i click on it. How do i prevent the re-login?

Also, my domain is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Marketing cloud access first.
Then you can enable SSO in your SFMC and the SFDC instance
It'll auto login every time you click into "Send Marketing Cloud email".